# Extending a PHP class

Tags: php, oop, class, abstract, extend

Just a quick question really.

I am re-writing a site and I am converting it all to OOP and putting it all into templates.

I have multiple classes, but I want to extend one of them from a separate file/class.

Do I have to require_once() the parent class to extend it?

I'm guessing you do but I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nomally it's neat to define an autoloader when you want to include a bunch of classes from a bunch of different files such as:

```
function __autoload( $className ) {
    $className = str_replace( "..", "", $className );
    require_once( "classes/$className.php" );
    // echo "Loaded classes/$className.php";
}
```

And then load whatever class name you have, i.e.:

```
$member = new Member();
```

Comment: That is exactly the info I was looking for, between yourself and Joe that is very useful :) Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, or you can look at http://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register to write a simple autoloader.

Answer (score 4):

Of course **NO**.
Don't write code in PHP4-style.
Use autoloading, namespaces and naming standards: [PSR-0](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have, otherwise the class wouldn't "exist" to PHP. 
Also, if you have some sensible naming convention, you should have a look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).